# Android HTTP connection refused error even after appropriate permissions

Tags: android, apache, http

I have this in my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.*****.****">
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

and this code in doInBackground (I know HttpGet is deprecated)

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        URI website = new URI(url);
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
```

getting  org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8080 refused error. Help me

Answer (score 3):

the ip addres 127.0.0.1 mean loopback. 
find right ip address.

what is loopback:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback

Comment: Am the dumbest person on earth, forgot the fact that am running server on desktop and app runs on my phone !! 
Thanks a lot.