# Android Studio - Gradle build error: "Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8080 refused"

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-2.2

I'm developing a game in Android Studio and have recently migrated to a new machine after the old one gave up the ghost. I have a fresh Android Studio 2.2.2 installation. When the gradle build process kicks off, it fails at the "resolve dependencies" step. Digging into the Gradle Build log, I see that the connection to localhost is being refused: "Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8080 refused"

My build.gradle file looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "Game Name"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.3'
        roboVMVersion = '2.1.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

The gradle build log is below. For each of the dependencies gradle is trying to resolve I get the same failure (i.e. each fails on connecting to localhost).

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'GameName'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6.
     Required by:
         :GameName:unspecified
      > Could not resolve de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/richsource/gradle/plugins/gwt-gradle-plugin/0.6/gwt-gradle-plugin-0.6.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/richsource/gradle/plugins/gwt-gradle-plugin/0.6/gwt-gradle-plugin-0.6.pom'.
               > Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8080 refused
      > Could not resolve de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6.
         > Could not get resource 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/de/richsource/gradle/plugins/gwt-gradle-plugin/0.6/gwt-gradle-plugin-0.6.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/de/richsource/gradle/plugins/gwt-gradle-plugin/0.6/gwt-gradle-plugin-0.6.pom'.
               > Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8080 refused
      > Could not resolve de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/de/richsource/gradle/plugins/gwt-gradle-plugin/0.6/gwt-gradle-plugin-0.6.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/de/richsource/gradle/plugins/gwt-gradle-plugin/0.6/gwt-gradle-plugin-0.6.pom'.
               > Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8080 refused
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2.
     Required by:
         :GameName:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.2/gradle-2.1.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.2/gradle-2.1.2.pom'.
               > Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8080 refused
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.2/gradle-2.1.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.2/gradle-2.1.2.pom'.
               > Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8080 refused
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.2/gradle-2.1.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.2/gradle-2.1.2.pom'.
               > Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8080 refused
   > Could not resolve com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         :GameName:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mobidevelop/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin/2.1.0/robovm-gradle-plugin-2.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mobidevelop/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin/2.1.0/robovm-gradle-plugin-2.1.0.pom'.
               > Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8080 refused
      > Could not resolve com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/mobidevelop/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin/2.1.0/robovm-gradle-plugin-2.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/mobidevelop/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin/2.1.0/robovm-gradle-plugin-2.1.0.pom'.
               > Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8080 refused
      > Could not resolve com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mobidevelop/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin/2.1.0/robovm-gradle-plugin-2.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mobidevelop/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin/2.1.0/robovm-gradle-plugin-2.1.0.pom'.
               > Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8080 refused
```

I'd greatly appreciate any help as I've been stuck on this for some time. Please let me know if any other information would be useful.

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: Refer the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253831/android-http-connection-refused-error-even-after-appropriate-permissions

Comment: Please edit the post, paste and indent the log with the code formatting button, so that it is easy to read and google.

Comment: @Ankit Thanks, although I'm not sure that fixes it for me - I've found similar links to the one you shared, where the problem is around invoking HTTP connections from within the application code itself, whereas I'm simply trying to build my code with Gradle.

Comment: @o2genum As requested (apologies - this is my first post in S/O so not overly familiar with how it works..). Any thoughts based on the log?

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file

Comment: Is it working in removing all mavenLocal() from your build.gradle ?

Comment: @Bipi No - still fails, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you mut any redirect in /etc/hosts file like : "127.0.0.1 repo1.maven.org" ?